# Codeigniter retrieve data immediately on controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I retrieve a data from my database in the controller, and assign it to a variable, that I will send to the view?

```
$data['schedule'] = $this->SectionsModel->getschedule($section);
```

I want the

> $schedule['teacher']

(as equivalent to a view) data from the statement above to be passed to a variable, but how?

I tried this one but it shows an error

```
    $data['schedule'] = $this->SectionsModel->getschedule($section);
        foreach ($data['schedule'] as $key => $value){
            echo $value['teacher'];
        }
```

Comment: What error result?

Comment: Undefined index: teacher

Comment: execute `var_dump($data['schedule'])` after you fill it and tell us what it outputs.

Comment: Yes, I tried that one, it outputs all the data in the schedule, but I only want to get the 'teachers'. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `getschedule()` method in your **SectionModel** if it's using the function **result()** instead of **result_array()**.

The difference between the two methods is that **result()** will return object while **result_array()** will return array.

In you case,

```
$data['schedule'] = $this->SectionsModel->getschedule($section);
foreach ($data['schedule'] as $key => $value){
  echo $value['teacher'];
}
```

Maybe **$data['schedule']** is an object.You must use,

```
$data['schedule'] = $this->SectionsModel->getschedule($section);
foreach ($data['schedule'] as $key => $value){
  echo $value->teacher;
}
```

If you will use **result_array()** method in your **getschedule()** in **SectionModel** to return result, do like this,

```
$data['schedule'] = $this->SectionsModel->getschedule($section);
foreach ($data['schedule'] as $key => $value){
  echo $value['teacher'];
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: The 'teacher' is a column in the database that is called in the function getschedule(), I want the 'teacher' value to be passed on a variable

Comment: I updated the answer, and you can do as mentioned above

Comment: Yes, I know that one, but I want it on the controller, not on the view because I will get another query for each of the rows' 'teacher' value

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use `result_array()` in return value of your model.

Comment: It's actually a result_array()